vite rolluptOptions entry with multiple js files
I try to convert a project built with wepack to vite js:
i had that :
   .addEntry("web_components", [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/components/comp1.js"),
        path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/components/comp2.js"),
        path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/components/comp3.js"),
    ])

so i want an entry that call multiple js files. i tried this :
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        input: {
            "web_components": [
                "./assets/components/comp1.js",
                "./assets/components/comp2.js",
                "./assets/components/comp3.js"
            ]
  }
 }
}

but i get an error, so is it possible to have an entry that load multiple js files with Vite ?
